# How do I build a node project during a visual studio build, separately from a C# project?

Tags: c#, node.js, .net-core, build

Visual Studio 2019 comes with Single Page App templates for .net Core apps. The React typescript template sets up the project like the following:

- Create a Solution in the `Project/Project.sln`
- Create an ASP.NET Core REST endpoint example in `Project/WebApi/WebApi.csproj`
- Contains a Single Page app in the `Project/WebApi/ClientApp` folder.
- Build that project as part of building the rest of that project.

I'd like to do the same, but instead of having the node project embedded in the C# project folder, have them be separate projects within the same solution. So instead of:

```
* Project/Project.sln
* Project/WebApi/Startup.cs // and all other C# code
* Project/WebApi/ClientApp/package.json // and all other node/typescript code
```

I'd rather set up the project like:

```
* Project/Project.sln
* Project/WebApi/Startup.cs // and all other C# code
* Project/ClientApp/package.json // and all other node/typescript code.
```

What's the best way to go about separating out the node project from the C# project, and still get it to all build as part of the solution's build?

Bonus: how do I do this with just the `dotnet` command?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea behind how this can be accomplished involves touching two things:

1. You have to be able to serve static content (or front-end libraries) from node_modules that will be located inside a separate project
2. Every time you build a project, `npm install` should be triggered to make sure that all front-end dependencies are in place.

To be able to serve from node_modules, you either have to modify the UseStaticFiles() middleware yourself, or use OdeToCode.UseNodeModules and tweak it so that the path points to the folder inside the different project.
Finally, automatic postbuild actions can be set up inside .csproj file. Sample:

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install"/>
  </Target>
```